# Why won't Unity SetActive execute within Input.GetButtonDown()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm completely stumped by this one. I have a book in game and when you are looking in its general direction while within a certain distance of it and press the Action button (e or left mouse click), it's supposed to display a UI panel (bookPage). Here's my code for it.

```
void Update () {
    Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - this.transform.position;
    angle = Vector3.Angle (direction, player.transform.forward);
    distance = direction.magnitude;
    if (angle >= 160 && distance <= 2 && !bookPage.activeSelf) {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action")) {
            bookPage.SetActive (true);
        }
    }
    if (bookPage.activeSelf && Input.GetButtonDown("Action")) {
        bookPage.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Specifically, the line to set the page to active doesn't work. If it's open, it will close correctly. If I copy and paste `bookPage.SetActive (true);`
anywhere within this method besides within `if(Input.getButtonDown("Action")){}`, it will make the bookPage active. If I put `Debug.Log("message");` within that if statement though, it will show up in the console. It's just the one line that sets bookPage to active that isn't working. I have no idea why. I've tried moving it to a different method then calling it and doing the same but using a Coroutine. Neither worked. I also tried using other keys which did work, but I need it to work with the action key. It's also worth noting that the action key works in other usage. I already use it to open doors. Has anyone else run into a problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `SetActive(true)`, `activeSelf` will return `true` for your second condition which will invoke `SetActive(false)` immediately after.

Change this;

```
if (angle >= 160 && distance <= 2 && !bookPage.activeSelf)
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
    {
        bookPage.SetActive(true);
    }
}
if (bookPage.activeSelf && Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
{
    bookPage.SetActive(false);
}
```

To this;

```
if (angle >= 160 && distance <= 2 && !bookPage.activeSelf)
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
    {
        bookPage.SetActive(true);
    }
}
else if (bookPage.activeSelf && Input.GetButtonDown("Action"))
{
    bookPage.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been staring at this for way too long and couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: @DavidMenear If this answer solved your issue, don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.